# prototypeJS-bootstrap datepicker conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prototypejs

It seems that I'm facing a conflict between prototypejs and jquery. Here is a sample of code to illustrate that (I know it's not very nice, i've created it for debugging purposes only) :

```
    <html> <head>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CR0000086/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- bug here if I add this line : <script type="text/javascript" src="/CR0000086/js/prototype.js"></script> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CR0000086/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CR0000086/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    </head> <body>

    <!-- test1 with datepicker --> 
    <input type="text" id="example1" class="hasDatePicker"> <script>
        $("#example1").datepicker(); </script>

    <!-- test2 with pickadate-->
    <div class="form-group">      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="date-input form-control"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="date-button btn btn-default" type="button"> @ </button>
            </span>   </div>   <div id="date-picker"> </div> </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CR0000086/css/pickadate.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CR0000086/js/pickadate.js"></script>

    </body> </html>
```

The page works well, I see my two datepickers, however, if I uncomment the line to load prototype.js, I get the following errors :

```
Cannot read property 'datepicker' of null
Cannot read property 'pickadate' of null
```

If you want to reproduce that bug, here is are the links to the packages I've used :

- http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/
- https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox

I've tried a lot of solutions, including JQuery.noConflict(), I guess that the solution has to deal with this bug : http://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/BootstrapPrototypeConflict

But I must admit that's a too high level in javascript for me, I need help to make one of these datepickers working **with** prototypeJS loaded.

Could you help me ? Or if you have another solution (I need a datepicker), any idea would be appreciated

Best regards,

Julien

Comment: I've successfully used https://github.com/joshsalverda/datepickr with prototypejs.

Comment: I confirm, datepickr is working fine, thanks a lot T. Gibbons ! However, it's a workaround solution. The root bug remains and I think that a real solution could help other devs..